# Проблема со считыванием в IntelliJ Idea

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, исключения

Проблема появилась недавно, решения не нашел. Именно в IntelliJ любой код, считывающий строку с преобразованием в Int, стал выдавать `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`. В Android Studio и в онлайн-редакторе на hyperskill.org код работает, а в IntelliJ нет. Причем примечательно то, что выдает он это после второго считывания, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что еще более примечательно, прямо сейчас в процессе написания этого текста я обнаружил, что те же операции без перевода в Int завершаются после второго считывания, но без ошибок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

IntelliJ переустанавливал, проект пересоздавал, но не помогло. Может кто знает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951/Console-readLine-skips-input-in-2022-1-1 баг idea  2022.1.1, будет исправлен в 2022.1.2

Comment: @IR42 спасибо! Буду знать, где искать в следующий раз